# Foundation's switch is not working well with toggleClass

Tags: jquery, css, zurb-foundation

Hi I need some help on foundation,

I've been using this switch for awhile 
http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/switch.html

I've wanted to add some toggleClass event when clicking on it but it won't let me, 
addClass works but toggleClass does not

```
$('.switchClassNameHere').on("click", function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('test');
});
```

I have tried this code and it worked but sadly the Switch won't work properly.

```
$('.switchClassNameHere').on("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).toggleClass('test');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reason `click` event triggered twice when you click on Foundation checkbox. Just add `console.log('test');` inside of your click handler to ensure. So `.toggleClass('test')` works twice: add class then remove.

You can use something like this instead of `toggleClass`:

```
$('.switchClassNameHere').on("click", function () {
    if($(this).find('input:checked').length === 0) {
        $(this).removeClass('test');
    } else { 
        $(this).addClass('test');
    }
});
```